# How do I expand a selection in Jmol to include entire residues?

Tags: biochemistry, software

I know how to select by distance in Jmol:

> select within(5, ATP)

This selects atoms that are within 5 Angstroms of ATP residues. How do I expand the selection to include the entire residues of the selected atoms?

I checked the [Jmol documentation](https://chemapps.stolaf.edu/jmol/docs/) and the [Jmol wiki](https://wiki.jmol.org/index.php/Selecting), searching for "expanding selection" but did not find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand the selection, use

> select within(group, selected)

This will select all groups (i.e. residues, nucleotides, etc) that have at least one atom selected already.

Examples can be found at https://chemapps.stolaf.edu/jmol/docs/examples-12/new2.htm after searching for "within(group".